# Armbian [Orange PI] remote connection

Tags: gnu-screen, putty, armbian

I'm trying to connect to an Orange PI lite `Armbian_5.38_Orangepilite_Debian_stretch_next_4.14.14.7z` with a FTDI cable `USB => serial` using `screen` or `putty` and connection is fine.

I can see the boot phase but then, how to interact with it ? I can't type any command

[image: screen]

[image: putty]

Answer (score 1):

Wrong cable, wrong order. For information, Orange PI right order is

`[RX, TX, GND]`

and FTDI colors are:

[image]

so:

`[white, green, black]`